# asp.net problem

Tags: asp.net

```
selectCourseList.SelectedIndex=Convert.ToInt32(selectCourseList.Items.FindByValue(newStudentCourseId));
```

giving following error
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

i don't understand whats wwrong with this

Comment: Actually, I dont understand, what do you want to do? be a specific pls

Comment: i have got newly added students courseId "newStudentCourseId" in string form, and i have a list box in which i want to set selected index of course to newly students added courseid

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
selectCourseList.Items.FindByValue(newStudentCourseId)
```

The above is going to give you a ListItem back, so you can't use Convert.ToInt32 and then set the index the way you're describing.

Instead try:

```
selectCourseList.Items.FindByValue(newStudentCourseId).Selected = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

selectCourseList.Items.FindByValue(newStudentCourseId) is returning some object that does not support the System.IConvertible interface - so the Convert.ToInt32 call is failing

What type of objects are in selectCourseList.Items ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert a ListItem to an int.  Try:

```
selectCourseList.SelectedIndex=selectCourseList.Items.IndexOf(selectCourseList.Items.FindByValue(newStudentCourseId));
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sur that the item value is a int type? 
Are you sur that the method FindByValue dont return a null for your parameter newStudentCourseId

Comment: find by value talkes string parameter so i converted it to string type wile i was getting it int type ...but i had reconverted it to int type by using convertToInt32 but of no avail whats wrong i am not getting but i have got solution to my problem by seeing above solution but can u tell whats wrong in this

Answer (score 0):

I think something like (not tested):

```
selectCourseList.SelectedIndex=-1;
selectCourseList.Items.FindByValue(newStudentCourseId).Selected = true;
```

where newStudentCourseId is a string representig the ItemValue of your DropDown.

Comment: find by value talkes string parameter so i converted it to string type wile i was getting it int type ...but i had reconverted it to int type by using convertToInt32 but of no avail whats wrong i am not getting but i have got solution to my problem by seeing above solution but can u tell whats wrong in this

Answer (score 0):

Surely you need;

```
selectCourseList.SelectedIndex=selectCourseList.IndexOf(selectCourseList.Items.FindByValue(newStudentCourseId));
```